# Google Tag Manager not including Universal Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I have a site that the Tag Assistant extension shows is loading GTM, but not our Universal Analytics code. What is strange about this is, this site has the same URL structure as all of our other sites. I exported a known working container and imported into this site, changing only the Universal Analytics variable, and it still doesn't work.

Even stranger. When I open preview mode from GTM, it shows everything firing as it should: Universal Analytics and Data Layers. We offer a cookie-cutter white-label solution in our industry and this same setup works for all other customers.

I've published again. I've wiped out the container and rebuilt it.

Any ideas about what to look for?

Comment: can you provide screenshots of the triggers that are used?